# Flex Mobile: List flickers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, mobile

Ok I have a List with an IconItemRenderer in it. When I set it's dataprovider in AS3 and I begin scrolling, the list is flickering one time (gets white for one frame). This only happens when the messageField/messageFunction is set and there is a different number of lines in the message areas. I'm sure this is a framework bug. Has anyone had the same experience? I would be glad if someone knows a workaround for this. Thanks in advance.

---

Here's an example code for a view component. Strange to say the flickering seems to take sometimes more, sometimes less time. I tested it on Android and in Desktop mode (adl), error occures on both. The "blabla.." is just to get a string with a random number of lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button label="Set List" click="btn_click(event)"/>
    </s:actionContent>
    <s:List width="100%" height="100%" id="list">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer messageField="text"/>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            protected function btn_click(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var al:ArrayList = new ArrayList;
                var obj:Object;
                var str:String = "blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabblablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabblablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla";
                for(var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    obj = new Object;
                    obj.text = str.substr(0, Math.random()*str.length);
                    al.addItem(obj);
                }
                list.dataProvider = al;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

---

See bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33383

For the workaround see the correct answer below.

Comment: How are you sure this is a framework bug? Have you tracked the buggy framework code? It might be helpful to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Show some code that we can run to demo the problem.  Also mention which mobile OS is exhibiting the problem.

Comment: @RIAstar No I haven't figured the the buggy code yet that's why I post this here. I diffucult because it's something event specific which is harder to debug.

Comment: @Flextras I added an example code in my question

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behaviour (desktop). Have you tried creating a separate class that extends `IconItemRenderer`? That should already be better for performance than creating an inline component like that.

Comment: Yes, in the real app I created a subclass of IconItemRenderer. I didn't do this in this example but the behavior occures independetly of this. Have you tried this several times? This behavior only occures once per component initialiation resp. app restart. I needed 3 tries in this example. If I shorten the "blabla" string to approx. one quarter it occures more often (in fact every time) to me. If I hit the "Set List" button two or more times before start scrolling it occures never. It's kind of laughable.

Comment: Yes, I see it too now. Very strange indeed. I think I managed to find a workaround (answer's coming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a workaround. Basically it's just faking a drag event when the list dispatches the updateComplete event. This prevents the flickering when the user first starts to scroll and since updateComplete is called before the list is initially shown, there is no flickering at all. The positive side effect is that every time you change to a view with this list in it or when the list gets another data provider, the scroll bar is shown for a moment, so you can guess how large the list is without touching it.

So here's the code. I use this list as a superclass for all of my lists:

```
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
import mx.events.TouchInteractionEvent;
import spark.components.List;

public class MyList extends List
{
    public function MyList()
    {
        super();

        //add event listeners
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, updateCompleteHandler);
    }

    //update complete
    protected function updateCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        //fake touch start
        fakeTouchEvent(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START);
        callLater(endTouch);
    }

    //quit touch event
    protected function endTouch():void {
        //fake touch end
        fakeTouchEvent(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_END);
    }

    //fake touch event
    protected function fakeTouchEvent(type:String):void {
        var evt:TouchInteractionEvent = new TouchInteractionEvent(type);
        evt.relatedObject = scroller;
        scroller.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have a workaround for you. The problem seems to be related to content justification, so I tried to change the default justification by setting a custom layout with `contentJustify` instead of the default `justify`:

```
<s:VerticalLayout gap="0" 
                  horizontalAlign="contentJustify" 
                  requestedMinRowCount="5" />
```

This fixed the flicker issue for me, but now the List could also scroll sideways, which was also undesired. This I fixed by setting the `horizontalScrollPolicy` to `off`. This is the final result:

```
<s:List width="100%" height="100%" id="list" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer messageField="text"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" r
                          equestedMinRowCount="5" />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

You may want to file this bug officially, though I don't exactly know where you'd have to do that now that Flex is moving from Adobe to Apache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't confirm that this works though. There's still the flickering for me.

Comment: @Flexx Really? It's consistently smooth here. And if I remove the `layout` tag and the `horizontalScrollPolicy` attribute it goes straight back to flickering.

Comment: No unfortunately it's the same behavior as before. I just found out that setting useVirtualLayout=false in the list works fine for me. Although I assume for performance/memory reasons on (larger) mobile lists this is a quite unsatisfactory solution. I would prefer your workaround if it worked for me.

Comment: @Flexx I tried `useVirtualLayout` before I came up with the justification solution: it didn't work for me. Very peculiar! BTW, I'm using Flex 4.6: perhaps we have a difference there?

Comment: Jeah 4.6, same here. Maybe you didn't set useVirtualLayout to true again after testing that? After profiling I was confirmed that I have to set useVirtualLayout=true due to the limited mobile memory. That's a brain twister.

Comment: @Flexx The JIRA bug tracker seems to have moved to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX

Comment: But "Please avoid adding duplicate tickets to JIRA. We are currently waiting for Adobe to commit their existing JIRA tickets."

Comment: @Flexx Just a rectification: it would seem that I was using Flex 4.5.1 after all. The project had another SDK than the default and I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I do too see this issue (Flex 4.6 + AIR 3.1), exactly as described: White flickering occurs only one time, when List is dragged in either direction. It doesn't happen on touch. In my case I don't even use Label/IconItemREnderer, rather I've build a custom ItemRenderer based on this pretty descent [walk through here](http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/mobile-itemrenderer-in-actionscript-part-4)
My measure() method doesn't use setElementSize() at all. The issue doesn't happen when virtualLayout=false, which is not acceptable on mobile for large (>200) elements in data provider. Sorry, have no workaround yet.